# How short can this script be and still achieve the same thing - display a message "loading.." followed by an extra period every 1 second for 7 seconds

Tags: javascript

```
<script>

    var dot = ".";
    var counter = 0;
    var message = "Loading Page";

    function writeLoadingMessage(){
        if (counter > 6) return;

        setTimeout('writeMessage();',1000);

    }

    function writeMessage(){

        document.getElementById('loadingMessageSpan').innerHTML = message + dot;
        message += dot
        counter++
        writeLoadingMessage();

        }

</script>


<BODY>

    <span style="font-weight:bold;" id="loadingMessageSpan"></span>

    <SCRIPT>writeLoadingMessage();</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function(){var i=6,a=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('loadingMessageSpan').innerHTML+=".";!i--&&clearInterval(a);},1E3)})()
```

You will need to have Loading already in your span tag.  As a note it is pointless to worry about getting it this small though.  Also, the page will will have to be already loaded.

Comment: It's short for 1000. 10,000 would be 1E4. The E(number) represents how many zeros are supposed to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it shorter: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/wBFSy/.

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;

    function writeMessage() {
        document.getElementById('loadingMessageSpan').innerHTML += ".";

        if(++counter < 7) {
            setTimeout(writeMessage, 1000);
        }
    }

    window.onload = writeMessage;
</script>

<body>
    <span style="font-weight:bold;" id="loadingMessageSpan">Loading Page</span>
</body>
```

[Minifying](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) also helps :)

```
var a=0;function b(){document.getElementById("loadingMessageSpan").innerHTML+=".";++a<7&&setTimeout(b,1E3)}window.onload=b
```

Comment: what is the difference between ++a and a++

Comment: @user521180: `++a` increments `a` with `1` and returns the new value. `a++` does the same, except that it returns the old (not incremented) value.

Answer (score 1):

1) User [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead.

2) Just set the message once and append . to end

3) Put all the js at the bottom

```
<body>    
<span style="font-weight:bold;" id="loadingMessageSpan">Loading Page</span>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('loadingMessageSpan').innerHTML += ".";
        if(++counter>6) {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it short you can go this route:

```
<BODY>
    <span style="font-weight:bold;" id="loadingMessageSpan">Loading Page</span>
    <script>
        var counter = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
          document.getElementById('loadingMessageSpan').innerHTML += ".";
          if(++counter > 6)
            clearInterval(interval);
        },1000)
    </script>
</BODY>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kc3fb/2/

Comment: The span isn't available until after the page has been loaded so getElementById above will throw an error if the page has half loaded but not the span. Better to put it at the bottom.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar good point!  I've edited my post. Thanks for pointing that out.